# LD_LIBRARY_PATH not being used

Tags: shared-libraries, system, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to link a shared object using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but it doesn't seem to be working on ubuntu 16 (strangely it works on Ubuntu 18). Here's an example in docker https://github.com/schneems/libpq_heroku_16_reproduction/tree/schneems/manually-download-install (note this is a branch).

I'm trying to link `libpq` version `5.12.1` which i've downloaded and then manually installed to a specific path. However when I run with `LD_DEBUG=libs` then I see that `libpq.so` is being loaded without searching `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

```
testcase_1  |          1:   find library=libpq.so.5 [0]; searching
testcase_1  |          1:    search path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu      (system search path)
testcase_1  |          1:     trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libpq.so.5
testcase_1  |          1:     trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libpq.so.5
testcase_1  |          1:     trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libpq.so.5
testcase_1  |          1:     trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5
testcase_1  |          1:
testcase_1  |          1:   find library=libssl.so.1.0.0 [0]; searching
testcase_1  |          1:    search path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu      (system search path)
testcase_1  |          1:     trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
testcase_1  |          1:    search path=/deb_dir/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:tls/x86_64:tls:x86_64:       (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
testcase_1  |          1:     trying file=/deb_dir/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
testcase_1  |          1:     trying file=tls/x86_64/libssl.so.1.0.0
testcase_1  |          1:     trying file=tls/libssl.so.1.0.0
testcase_1  |          1:     trying file=x86_64/libssl.so.1.0.0
testcase_1  |          1:     trying file=libssl.so.1.0.0
testcase_1  |          1:    search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
testcase_1  |          1:     trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

Here you can see the first call doesn't use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at all (for libpq), but the second does (for libssl).

Does anyone know why a specific shared object lookup might not use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or why this would work on ubuntu 18 but not ubuntu 16 (heroku-16 versus heroku-18 docker images)?

Comment: Possibly answered here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449060/are-there-any-circumstances-in-which-ld-ignores-ld-library-path